# Create an object with custom structure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array object with this exact structure:

```
{"item1": {
    0 :  {
        color:"description1",
        width:"description2",
        height:"description3"
    }
    1 :  {
        color:"description1",
        width:"description2",
        height:"description3"
    }
    //and so on
},
"item2": {
    0 :  {
        color:"description1",
        width:"description2",
        height:"description3"
    }
    //and so on
}
//and so on
}
```

Estatically works fine. Now, I want to make it dinamically. So, the main question is... How can I loop the data while constructing the object at the same time?
This is an example of the incoming object I work from:

```
[
{
    "uid": 1,
    "legendname": "item1",
    "rows": [
        {
            "uid": 0,
            "color": "482400",
            "width": "482400",
            "height": "25"
        },
        {
            "uid": 1,
            "color": "587898",
            "width": "789658",
            "height": "30"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "uid": 2,
    "legendname": "item2",
    "rows": [
        {
            "uid": 0,
            "color": "482400",
            "width": "482400",
            "height": "25"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: I tried something, but appears that what you want to achieve is not entirely clear to me. Mind elaborating?

Comment: EricG, thanks for the support. The answer given below by donkeydown works for me. I wanted to create dinamically an object with an exact structure (what I showed in the post). I looped data and created a string with my object structure. But the data type was an string and I needed an object type to run in the app. I didn´t know how to do it, but it´s solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How can I loop the data while constructing the object at the same time?*

Is not clear. But if you want to create a new structure based on the incoming one, you can use this:

```
// ar = your incoming object
// b_obj = your result

var b_obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
{
    item = ar[i];
    b_item = {};
    for (var i_row = 0; i_row < item.rows.length; i_row++)
    {
        var row = {};
        row.color = item.rows[i_row].color;
        row.width = item.rows[i_row].width;
        row.height = item.rows[i_row].height;
        b_item[i_row] = row;
    }
    b_obj[item.legendname] = b_item;
}
```

Comment: If that is the answer you should approve it.

Comment: Or at least give a +1.

Comment: @user2932685 +1 goes to the Answer, not the comment.

Comment: That would increase reputation score.

Comment: donkeydown, It was the first thing I tried to do, but I´m new in this forum and my reputation is lower than 15, so unafortunately I can´t push +1 button now. If I get +15 reputation I´ll come back to this post to give you the +1 that you deserve.

Comment: yes, there you have =). I though that the "check" had something to do with the +1. I already marked as the right answer.